# Failing to write an XML file on WinXp

Tags: c#, xml, backgroundworker

i've a problem in my program: running Win XP, it is impossible to write an XML file inside the backgroundworker's doWork();

here is the code inside the BW:

```cs
try
{
    updateUI(file.FullName, 2);
    writeToXml(file, e.Argument.ToString());
}
```

the creation of xml file:

```
XDocument xmlDocVideoList = new XDocument(
                                 new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                                 new XComment("..."),
                                 new XElement(/*ns+*/"VideoList"));
xmlDocVideoList.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
```

the writeToXml method:

```
 public void writeToXml(FileInfo file, string path)
    {
        fileCounterMapped++;
        Video temp = new Video();
        temp.nameFile = file.Name;
        temp.nameVideo = temp.processNameFile(temp.nameFile);
        temp.path = file.Directory.FullName;

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);

        XmlNode node = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Video", null);
        XmlNode subnodeFN = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "FileName", null);
        XmlNode subnodeVN = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "VideoName", null);
        XmlNode subnodePATH = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Path", null);

        subnodeFN.InnerText = temp.nameFile;
        subnodeVN.InnerText = temp.nameVideo;
        subnodePATH.InnerText = temp.path;

        node.AppendChild(subnodeFN);
        node.AppendChild(subnodeVN);
        node.AppendChild(subnodePATH);


        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(node);

        doc.Save(path);
    }
```

In my computer, running Win7 this WORKS, but in all the PC with WinXP doesn't work.
In all computer I use VisualStudio 10 Express and I have the FrameWork 4.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't work means :"Everything looks fine, no exception, no odd log, but no file written" ?

Comment: The file is written but with almost nothing inside. Moreover in the BW I have a delegate that updates a TextBox, like a log, and that works!
The XML have just this inside:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--XML file for the VideoList mapped in your folders.-->
<VideoList />

Comment: @user2424743 subscribe to `RunWorkerCompleted` event and check if `e.Error` has some exception inside

Comment: does the XP station has .net 4 installed on it? is your code working without the BackgroundWorker?

Comment: I resolved the problem: there was an Exception inside the writeXML method and I didn't put any catch Exception there, so I didn't see anything!
Thanks all and sorry for newbye mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

The XDocument Object Belongs to newer versions of .Net maybe try using only the XMLDocument instead.

If you're using .NET version 3.0 or lower, you have to use XmlDocument aka the classic DOM API ... maybe xp isnt supporting this or maybe you need to update your windows.